# Fail to get value with xpath in php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm having trouble getting a value from an xml string.
$query_return_string contains the following as a string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/rf1/result">
  <head>
    <variable name="label"/>
  </head>
  <results>
    <result>
      <label>Demo sports 3</label>
    </result>
  </results>
</sparql>
```

This is the php code:

```
<?php
if ($query_return_string) {
  $query_return_dom = DOMDocument::loadXML($query_return_string);

  $xpath_dom = new DOMXPath($query_return_dom);

  $xpath = '//label';

  $entries = $xpath_dom->query($xpath);
  dsm($entries->length);
  // /sparql/results/result/label
}
?>
```

I'm not even bothering trying to go over the object to get the value because $entries->length returns 0.
What could I be doing wrong? This seems pretty basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register the namespace.

```
$xpath_dom->registerNamespace('sw', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/rf1/result');
$xpath = '//sw:label';
```

etc.